# How can I check this in SQL query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am learning SQL Query language. My task is to compare id numbers in local variable. I am trying to write an ID_number check script whick contains if-es. I have character checker and length checker.
Conditions:

```
 - 2 letter + space + 6 numbers, pl.: AE 232323 then it is okay.
 - 2 letter + dash + Roman Number + space + 6 Numbers, pl.: AU-I 123456 not valid
 - 6 numbers + 2 letters, pl.: 123456AA
```

I have these:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  p_idn students.id_number%TYPE;
  v_idn_check_result INT;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Length based testing: ');
  p_idn := 'me234158';
  v_idn_check_result := check_idn(p_idn);
  IF v_idn_check_result = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Okay');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
  END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Character based testing ');
  p_idn := '01201201x';
  v_idn_check_result := sf_check_idn(p_idn);
  IF v_idn_check_result = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OKAY');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
  END IF;
END;
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Which dbms???  SQL is just a language used by multiple vendors.

Comment: I'm using sqldeveloper. Oracle

Comment: You could use a regex match to check if a dash exists in your string (the dash seems to be the main issue, so I'd check this first) [See this link](https://www.salvis.com/blog/2018/09/28/regular-expressions-sql-examples/)

Comment: SQLDeveloper is not a dbms.

Comment: Please add Oracle tag to your question.

Comment: SQL Query Language is redundant.  " Structured Query Language Query Language"

Comment: So, what's the problem? Are your `check_idn` and `sf_check_idn` functions working as expected?

Comment: Also, there is no SQL query in your question after the title. What you have is a PL/SQL block. SQL and PL/SQL are two different things.

Comment: Let's ignore all the nitpicking regarding language names and so forth, and focus on the main point: what is your question? Have you written the procedures `check_idn()` and `sf_check_idn()`? Or are you hoping we'll write them for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to creating functions to satisfy your condition. As an example am sharing the solution for  case1. For the other 2 case you can build the `function` on the similar lines.

```
DECLARE
    p_idn                VARCHAR2(10);
    v_idn_check_result   INT;
---Function to handle first case

    FUNCTION check_idn (
        p_idn VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN NUMBER IS
        var1   NUMBER;
        var2   NUMBER;
        var3   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        var1   := ascii(substr(p_idn, 1, 1) );
        var2   := ascii(substr(p_idn, 2, 1) );
        var3   := substr(p_idn, 3);

        IF   --Checking if first character is a alphabet
            ( var1 BETWEEN 65 AND 90 ) OR ( var1 BETWEEN 97 AND 122 )
        THEN
            IF   --Checking if second character is a alphabet
                ( var2 BETWEEN 65 AND 90 ) OR ( var2 BETWEEN 97 AND 122 )
            THEN
                IF --Checking if length is 6 character
                    length(var3) = 6
                THEN --Checking if last 6 character are number
                    var3   := to_number(var3);
                ELSE
                    RETURN 1;
                END IF;

                RETURN 0;
            ELSE
                RETURN 1;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN value_error THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Value Error -->'
            || sqlerrm);
            RETURN 1;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Error -->'
            || sqlerrm);
            RETURN 1;
    END;

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put('Length based testing: ');
    p_idn                := '&input';
    v_idn_check_result   := check_idn(p_idn);
    IF
        v_idn_check_result = 0
    THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Okay');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');
    END IF;

END;
```

Note then once you execute it, it will prompt you to input the string. You need to input the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate each of pattern with a regexp. But please explain why you say "AU-I 123456" as it exactly follows your stated requirement:  
   2 letter + dash + Roman Number + space + 6 Numbers

- 'AU'      ->  2 letters
- '-'       ->  dash
- 'I'       ->  Roman numeral 1
- ' '       ->  space
- '123456'  ->  6 Numbers

The following shows the regexp used for each requirement.

- 2 letter + space + 6 numbers, pl.: AE 232323 then it is okay.
   regexp: ^[A-Z]{2} \d{6}$
- 2 letter + dash + Roman Number + space + 6 Numbers, pl.: AU-I 123456 not valid
   regexp: ^[A-Z]{2}-[IVXLCMivxlcm]+ \d{6}$
- 6 numbers + 2 letters, pl.: 123456AA
   regexp: ^\d{6}[A-Z]{2}$

And the queries:  
Without RegExp for Roman Numerals

```
with test_set as
     ( select 'AE 232323'  stg from dual union all 
       select 'AU-I 123456'    from dual union all    
       select '123456AA'       from dual
     )
select stg,case when regexp_like(stg, '(^[A-Z]{2} \d{6}$|^\d{6}[A-Z]{2}$)') then 'Good' else 'Invalid' end  id_ok 
  from test_set;
```

And with RegExp for Roman Numerals

```
with test_set as
     ( select 'AE 232323'  stg from dual union all 
       select 'AU-I 123456'    from dual union all    
       select '123456AA'       from dual
     )
select stg,case when regexp_like(stg, '(^[A-Z]{2} \d{6}$|^\d{6}[A-Z]{2}$)|^[A-Z]{2}-[IVXLCMivxlcm]+ \d{6}$') then 'Good' else 'Invalid' end  id_ok 
  from test_set;
```